# Prevent CSS duplication in Webpack chunks when using code split

Tags: webpack, less, code-duplication, splitchunksplugin

I'm on a projet using LESS imported from JS bundled by `webpack`4.

My problem is that the project have its own design-system, with components using same components like "typography"

Example:
I have a button that import `typo.less`.
So all my chunks using that button will generate the result of `typo.less`.
How can I prevent this duplication?
`splitChunks` seems not to operate here.

Comment: It's a pity you didn't show the webpack code.
I understand that in one css file you get a duplicate of these styles?
Therefore, I suggest using the postcss-loader and the cssnano plugin in the webpack. On this page you can see how it duplicates [cssnano](https://cssnano.co/playground/).
Here's an example of using postcss-loader [webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js#L106)

Comment: Same issue here, it seems when specifying custom chunks, some imported css from chunk vendors gets duplicated into the custom chunk

Comment: We decided to move to CSS module to avoid conflict